# How to factor a 200-digit number that has two factors known to have ~100 digits each?

Tags: factoring, cryptography

Suppose I have a set of 200-digit numbers that were created from the product of two randomly chosen 100 digit primes, P and Q. Considering that these 200-digit moduli have withstood a continued fraction attack (https://sagi.io/2016/04/crypto-classics-wieners-rsa-attack/), and Q is slightly larger than 2P, what is the best attack to use to factor the moduli?

p − 1 and q − 1 each have at least has at least one large prime factor

The paper at https://www.nku.edu/~christensen/Mathematical%20attack%20on%20RSA.pdf lists some of the factoring methods I have tried.

I am aware of cado-nfs (https://github.com/kurhula/cado-nfs) and yafu (https://github.com/DarkenCode/yafu/blob/master/README), and have used them to factor 100-digit moduli easily, but do not know how to tune the parameters to look for only 100-digit prime factors

Comment: How could $Q$ be larger than $P^2$ if they both have 100 digits?

Comment: That should be Q > 2p,

Comment: buy a bigger computer...

Comment: You tried computing the gcd's of all pairs of moduli? No common factors?

Comment: Correct, computing the gcd of all pairs of moduli did not produce any common factors. I've used that method before, and it has been helpful at times, but not for this set of moduli.